# How to close Rxtx serial port?

Tags: java, serial-port, timeout, rxtx

When [retrieving available serial ports](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Discovering_available_comm_ports) using the Rxtx library (see second example), the `close()` method will block, even if the port has been successfully opened.

How do I set a timeout on the close operation so I won't be stuck? Note that these methods are ***very poorly*** documented.

Note that I just found this relevant [thread](http://mailman.qbang.org/pipermail/rxtx/2005-March/9217403.html). I'll report back soon.

**Update -**

Here's another [thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1292323). Still no luck yet...

Comment: You might be interested in an alternative library I've authored: http://code.google.com/p/jperipheral

Comment: @Gili, Very interesting, I'll definitely take a look! Thanks :D